# C# OOP specific params while extending class

Tags: c#, class, oop, extends

I have a class ClassA that has a protected property of type class AttA, a class ClassB that extends from ClassA and a class AttB that extends from AttA.

In class ClassA I want to use the property AttA but in class ClassB I want to use the more specific property AttB.

Is there a way to do so?

```
class ClassA
{
    protected AttA att;

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // using att as AttA
    }
}
```

```
class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public override void MyMethod()
    {
         // Want to use att as AttB (if possible without downcasting)
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use the `new` keyword:

```
class ClassA
{
  protected AttA att;
  public virtual void MyMethod()
  {
  }
}

class ClassB : ClassA
{
  new protected AttB att;
  public override void MyMethod()
  {
  }
}

class AttA
{
}

class AttB : AttA
{
}
```

But this may causes problems on using polymorphism because writing:

```
var b = new ClassB();

//b.att is type of AttB here

var a = (ClassA)b;

//a.att is type of AttA here and it is not the same variable
```

In fact, there is two fields `att` depending of the type you manipulate, so be carefull in the classes implementations especially when calling base members from child class.

Since the field is protected this problem is limited.

On the contrary this may be exactly what is needed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier

---

*I tried to find a generic solution, but since C# does not support true generic polymorphism, and we can't constraint a generic type parameter on one type for one class type, this is impossible, as I know - or it requires writing some code using reflection which can be overengineered here unless it is necessary (thus it will be possible to have the same variable between classes hierarchy exposing the desired polymorphed type).*

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but `att` in `ClassB` is completely different object from that one which is in `ClassA`.

Comment: Indeed, I just added explanation about that.

Comment: Slight correction: OP states: *"... class AttB that extends from AttA"*

Comment: Can't you avoid the pitfall by writing `base.att = this.att;` in `ClassB`?

Comment: "Yes", we can magage that in a setter for `att` in the child class, but not in the mother class. Hence this is not clean at all nor consistent. Thus **NO** because the mother class does not know child classes (or we need to use "hard global and possibly lagging" reflection and for such thing I prefer the clean generic solution mentioned but it requires some devs to check and cast types at runtime).